# Layout flicker when dragging view in its MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, resize, layoutparams

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

So, I want to resize a single cell while dragging resize anchors (black quads) which are ImageViews. To do this I attached custom onTouchListener to them that does next in MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

- calculate drag offset
- set cell height/width based on this offset
- reposition anchor point by changing it's layout params

The outcome of this is that the cell resizes but there is some king of flicker, more like shaking left/right or up/down, by some small offset.

My guess is that the problem comes when it catches move event, then I manualy change position of anchor and then, when it catches move event again it doesn't handle that change well...or something

I have an idea to put invisible ImageViews under each anchor and do resize based on their movement but do not move that anchor while draging. Then when I relese it, it lines up with coresponding visible anchor. But this is more hacking than solution :)

And finally, does anubody know why is this happening?

EDIT:
Here is the code where I'm handlign move event:

```
float dragY = event.getRawY() - resizePreviousPositionY;

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams componentParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)selectedComponent.layout.getLayoutParams();
                    LinearLayout parrent = (LinearLayout)selectedComponent.layout.getParent();
                    View topSibling = parrent.getChildAt(parrent.indexOfChild(selectedComponent.layout) - 1);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams topSiblingParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)topSibling.getLayoutParams();

                    if(dragY > 0 && selectedComponent.layout.getHeight() > 100 ||
                            dragY < 0 &&  topSibling.getHeight() > 100)
                    {
                        componentParams.height = selectedComponent.layout.getHeight() - (int)dragY;
                        topSiblingParams.height = topSibling.getHeight() + (int)dragY;
                        //bottomSiblingParams.height = bottomSibling.getHeight();
                        selectedComponent.layout.setLayoutParams(componentParams);

                        repositionResizeAnchors(selectedComponent);
                    }
                    resizePreviousPositionY = event.getRawY();
```

and here is where I reposition it:

```
if(((LinearLayout)viewHolder.layout.getParent()).getOrientation() == LinearLayout.VERTICAL)
        {
            leftMargin = ((LinearLayout)viewHolder.layout.getParent()).getLeft() + 
                    viewHolder.layout.getLeft() + viewHolder.layout.getWidth()/2;
        }
        else
        {
            leftMargin = viewHolder.layout.getLeft() + viewHolder.layout.getWidth()/2;
        }
        topMargin = viewHolder.layout.getTop();
        params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)resizeTop.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin = leftMargin - dpToPx(resizeAnchorRadius/2);
        params.topMargin = topMargin - dpToPx(resizeAnchorRadius/2);
        resizeTop.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: dont use `MotionEvent.get*()`, use `MotionEvent.getRaw*()` instead, have you notice i didn't see your code at all?

Comment: Yeah, that solves the problem! But I would like to know why it in't working the other way, can you explain? I'l edit question to show you the code.

And, now I have other problem. While moving, the anchor is draging behind like it is chasing the view that I'm resizeing. The faster I move finger the more it falls behind

Comment: why does it work now? i'll leave it as your homework... ;) hint: Log.d **x/y** and **raw x/y** values

Comment: I'm guessing, based on output, that get* gives position in dp and getRax* in px, am I right?

And can you convert comment to answer so I can accept it?

Comment: both get position in px

Comment: I think I got it :) getRaw* returns absolute position of touch on the screen. And get* returns position relative to upperleft corner of touched view, am I right? Now it makes sense why it was bouncing :) But what with a new problem and draging behind?

Comment: @pskink x/y gives the ratio of screen height and width? i didn't get the relation why is it related to flickering issue? could you explain

Comment: @war_Hero what `x/y`?

Comment: in the above hint you gave x/y, i am struck in a same thing i just want to understand y the flickering happens

Comment: @war_Hero aaaa ok, i know it now ;-), its not "divide x by y" but rather `Log.d` the values of variables  "x and/or y" - in other words `Log.d` that was returned by getX()/Y()

Comment: @pskink ok, thanks for clarifing